# How does the browser know the correct URL path?

Tags: browser, https, hyperlink

Sorry for the basic question, but couldn't find a similar answer.

If I write this link: `<a href="/hello">click me</a>`.

On my HTML page, and host that page at `google.com` - When I navigate to that page the link will automagically link to `google.com/about`.

My question is, how does it do that? Does the browser just know the internal link from the page you are currently on? Is it the server calculating the links? How does it know to add the `google.com`?

I'm building a web crawler that finds links on a site (including these internal links), and not sure if I can just add in the `google.com` or if browsers work out internal links a different way.